# Help with a pivot query

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I've got data that goes sort of like this:

```
Time    Name    country
12      steve   brazil
12      mary    brazil
12      kate    usa
12      john    usa
13      paul    canada
13      tim     canada
```

How would i go about writing a pivot query so that it looks like this?:

```
Time    Name1    Name2   Country
12      steve    mary    brazil
12      kate     john    usa
13      paul     tim     canada
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are there always only 2 names for each `Time` and `Country`?  Also, does it matter which name is `Name1` and which name is `Name2`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a quick example of using `min` and `max` along with `group by` to produce a result that is similar to yours.

```
--Demo setup
drop table if exists table1
go
CREATE TABLE Table1 (
  Time INTEGER,
  Name VARCHAR(5),
  country VARCHAR(6)
);

INSERT INTO Table1
  (Time, Name, country)
VALUES
  ('12', 'steve', 'brazil'),
  ('12', 'mary', 'brazil'),
  ('12', 'kate', 'usa'),
  ('12', 'john', 'usa'),
  ('13', 'paul', 'canada'),
  ('13', 'tim', 'canada');

--Solution
SELECT [Time]
    ,min(NAME) AS Name1
    ,max(NAME) AS Name2
    ,Country
FROM table1
GROUP BY TIME
    ,country
ORDER BY [Time]
```

---

```
| Time | Name1 | Name2 | Country |
|------|-------|-------|---------|
| 12   | mary  | steve | brazil  |
| 12   | john  | kate  | usa     |
| 13   | paul  | tim   | canada  |
```