# How to PIVOT data from MSSQL query and Fetch to PHP view

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, php, pivot

I have a MSSQL 2005 Database with query content like this :

| nopas | code | name | order |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00115301 | D031 | ADAM | 1 |
| 00130015 | D031 | ADAM | 2 |
| 00149998 | D026 | JAMES | 1 |
| 00149970 | D028 | FIKI | 1 |
| 00142641 | D028 | FIKI | 2 |
| 00127700 | D028 | FIKI | 3 |

For report reason, I need Output a table like :

| ADAM | JAMES | FIKI | ...(dynamic content based new record) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00115301 | 00149998 | 00149970 | ... |
| 00130015 | - | 00142641 | ... |
| - | - | 00127700 | ... |

Can anyone help me??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Help with a pivot query](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/238324/help-with-a-pivot-query)

Answer (score 1):

You can do a pivot with `CASE` statements. It's basically the manual way of pivoting and if you were using a version of SQL Server before 2005, you would need to go that route. SQL Server 2005 added the [PIVOT function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot).

Because you need it to be dynamic, you will need to use [dynamic SQL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/odbc/reference/dynamic-sql). It's a lot of leg work but definitely doable.

I'm going to create your table content in a global temporary table (has to be global to work in dynamic SQL).

```
-- CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE
CREATE TABLE ##tablename (
  [nopas] VARCHAR(8),
  [code] VARCHAR(4),
  [name] VARCHAR(64),
  [order] SMALLINT
);

INSERT INTO ##tablename
  ([nopas], [code], [name], [order])
VALUES
 ('00115301','D031','ADAM',  1)
,('00130015','D031','ADAM',  2)
,('00149998','D026','JAMES', 1)
,('00149970','D028','FIKI',  1)
,('00142641','D028','FIKI',  2)
,('00127700','D028','FIKI',  3);
```

Next, I'm going to `SELECT` just the unique names into another temporary table and associate them with an `IDENTITY` with which I can iterate through in a for loop.

```
SELECT IDENTITY(INT, 1,1) as [id], [name] 
INTO #temp
FROM ##tablename
GROUP BY [name];
```

Now comes the difficult part. The `PRINT @dynSQL` generates what I'm trying to achieve dynamically (below). We need to `SELECT` the `[order]`, `[name]`, and `[nopas]` for the final result. We are pivoting on the `[name]` in the second part of the statement, and aggregating by `MAX([nopas])`; but because we contain an `[order]` grouping in your original table content, it will only retrieve the `MAX([nopas])` based on the `MAX` value of a single row. So, the result is that it removes aggregation. If you did not have an `[order]` column in your original content, we would need to use the [ROW_NUMBER() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql)* `PARTITIONED BY` the `[name]` to generate that `[order]`.

<s>*EDIT: I discovered that the `ROW_NUMBER()` function is only available in SQL Server 2012 and newer.*</s> *See [@Andriy M](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/6965/andriy-m)'s comment below.*

```
-- PRINT @dynSQL result
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT [order], [name], [nopas]
  FROM ##tablename) AS sourceTable
PIVOT(
MAX([nopas])
FOR [name] IN ([ADAM],[FIKI],[JAMES])
) AS pivotTable;
```

```
-- The leg work to create the dynamic SQL.
DECLARE @count INT = 1;
DECLARE @max INT = (SELECT MAX(id) FROM #temp);
DECLARE @dynSQL VARCHAR(2048) = 'SELECT * FROM
(SELECT [order], [name], [nopas]
  FROM ##tablename) AS sourceTable
PIVOT(
MAX([nopas])
FOR [name] IN (';

SET @count = 1;
WHILE(@count <= @max)
BEGIN
  SET @dynSQL += '[' + (SELECT [name] FROM #temp WHERE id = @count) + '],';
  SET @count += 1;
END

SET @dynSQL = LEFT(@dynSQL, DATALENGTH(@dynSQL) -1) + ')
) AS pivotTable;';

PRINT @dynSQL;
EXEC (@dynSQL);

DROP TABLE ##tablename;
DROP TABLE #temp;
```

---

Oh, if you want to remove the `[order]` column, from the result. You could  use `SELECT * INTO ##newGlobalTable` in the dynamic SQL and then `ALTER` the new table and `DROP` the column.

Comment: @pde, I've put the code, from this answer, into [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=b17e076b564fe6e8cf608a57b06647a4) with the extra steps to remove the `[order]` column.

Comment: I don't know why you thought `ROW_NUMBER()` became available only in SQL Server 2012, I'm guessing it's because that was the oldest version for which online documentation was available at the time of your post (and now the oldest one is 2016). Anyway, `ROW_NUMBER` has actually been available since SQL Server 2005, so it would work for the OP no problem.